# Real-time value in alert message

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

[image]

This is how TradingView sends a webhook to Telegram.

As shown in the photo, the close used as an alert message in the opening strategy informed the entry price of the position well.

However, in the case of a strategy exit, the close used as an alert message is sending the entry value, not the exit of the strategy.

What happens to the function that receives the correct actual value from the strategy exit?

Answer (score 0):

I think the placeholders `{{time}}` and/or `{{timenow}}` can help https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000531021
Use it in alertMessage4.